# How to separate wrapper values in JavaScript client side and after separation how to set the value to attributes

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning

[image]

```
<aura:component controller="ActionController"  implements="force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global">
<aura:attribute name="theId" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="options" type="String[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="wrplst" type="WrapperCriteria[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="selectedValue" type="String"/>
 <aura:attribute required="true" name="Components" type="String[]"/>
<aura:attribute required="true" name="Components1" type="String[]"/>

<aura:handler name="deleteJob" event="c:deleteJobEvt" action="{!c.RemoveClick}" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<p>
    <center><h5><b>Creating Action Criteria </b></h5></center>
</p>
<h3 class="slds-section-title--divider">
    <b>
        <I> Action Criteria</I>
    </b>
</h3>
<table >
    <tr class="slds-text-title--caps">
        <th class="head">
            <I>Action</I>
        </th>
        <th class="head">
            <I>Object Name</I>
        </th>
        <th class="head">
            <I>Component</I>
        </th>
        <th class="head">
            <I>Operator</I>
        </th>
        <th class="head">
            <I>Special Operator</I>
        </th>
        <th class="head">
            <I>Special Operator * Value</I>
        </th>
        <th class="head">
            <I>Special Operator / Value</I>
        </th>
    </tr>

    <aura:renderIf isTrue="{!v.wrplst.length > 0}">
       <aura:iteration items="{!v.wrplst}" var="a">
            <c:NewAction wrp="{!a}" options="{!v.options}" selectedValue=""  idval="{!v.theId}"/>
         </aura:iteration>
    </aura:renderIf>
</table>
<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Add row" onclick="{!c.AddRow}" />
<lightning:button variant="brand"  label="Save" onclick="{!c.saveRow}" />
```

Javascript side:

```
      ({
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.pageLoad(component);
    helper.componentVal(component);

},
doSomething: function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.Method2(component);
},
RemoveClick: function(component, event, helper) {
    var selCont = event.getParam("selectedJob");
    var conts = component.get("v.wrplst");
    var contsval = JSON.stringify(conts);

    var Selndex = conts.indexOf(selCont);

    var DeleteLen = conts.length;
    //alert('deleteLen value::::' + DeleteLen);
    var removeAction=component.get("c.removeRow");
    removeAction.setParams({
        "wrvalue":contsval,
        "rowval":Selndex 
    });
    removeAction.setCallback(this, function(g) {
        var state = g.getState();
        if (state == 'SUCCESS') {
            alert('success value');
            component.set("v.wrplst",JSON.parse(g.getReturnValue()));
        }
        else if(state==='error'){
            alert('error value');
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(removeAction);
},
AddRow: function(component, event, helper) {

    var comp1 = component.get("v.wrplst");
    var compJson1 = JSON.stringify(comp1);
    var mapRecords = new Array();
    for (i = 0; i < comp1.length; i++) {
        mapRecords.push(comp1[i]);
    }
    var len = mapRecords.length;

    var newlen = len + 1;

    var addAction = component.get("c.addRow");
    addAction.setParams({
        "wrapval": compJson1,
        "counterval": newlen,
    });
    addAction.setCallback(this, function(res) {
        var state = res.getState();
        if (state == 'SUCCESS') {
            component.set("v.wrplst", JSON.parse(res.getReturnValue()));
        } else if (state == 'ERROR') {
            alert('error');
        } else if (state == 'INCOMPLETE') {
            alert('incompltete');
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(addAction);
},
saveRow: function(component, event, helper) {
    var Idx = component.get("v.theId");
    alert('Id value ::::' + Idx);
    var com = component.get("v.wrplst");
    var comJson = JSON.stringify(com);

    var saveAction = component.get("c.saveCall");
    saveAction.setParams({
        "wrvalue": comJson,
        "id": Idx,
    });
    saveAction.setCallback(this, function(re) {
        var state = re.getState();
        if (state === 'SUCCESS') {

        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(saveAction);
}
```

### });

Helper:

```
({
      pageLoad: function(component, event) {
    var action = component.get("c.pageLoading");
    var self = this;
    var Idx = component.get("v.theId");
    action.setParams({
        "id": Idx
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(g) {
        var state = g.getState();
        if (state == 'SUCCESS') {

            component.set("v.wrplst",JSON.parse(g.getReturnValue()));
            self.Method2(component);

        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);

},

Method2: function(component, event, helper) {

    var comp = component.get("v.wrplst");
    var compJson = JSON.stringify(comp);
    var Id1 = component.get("v.theId");
    var compAction = component.get("c.getComponent");
    compAction.setParams({
        "wrapval": compJson,
        "id": Id1,
    });
    compAction.setCallback(this, function(re) {
        var state = re.getState();
        if (state ==='SUCCESS') {
        alert('::::::::::::::' +JSON.stringify(re.getReturnValue()));
      //var response = JSON.parse("{\"Components1\":[{\"value\":\"aId\"}], \"Components\":[{\"value\":\"CTC_Amount__c\"}]}");
   //var data = JSON.parse(response);



        }
        else if(state==='error'){
            alert('error value');
        }
            else if(state==='INCOMPLETE'){
                alert('incomplete values:::');

            }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(compAction);
},
componentVal:function(component,event,helper){

    var action=component.get("c.ObjectNames");
    action.setCallback(this,function(re){
        var state=re.getState();
        if(state==='SUCCESS'){

            component.set("v.options",JSON.parse(re.getReturnValue()));
        }
        else if(state==='Error'){
            alert('error');
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

### })

components1 values:[image]
components value:[image]

Java script alert value:

[image]

---

I have tried javascript code like this

```
   var compAction = component.get("c.getComponent");
    compAction.setParams({
        "wrapval": compJson,
        "id": Id1,
    });
    compAction.setCallback(this, function(re) {
        var state = re.getState();
        if (state ==='SUCCESS') {
               alert(':::Components :::'+JSON.parse(re.getReturnValue().Components));
                alert(':::Components1:::'+JSON.parse(re.getReturnValue().Components1));



        }
        else if(state==='error'){
            alert('error value');
        }
            else if(state==='INCOMPLETE'){
                alert('incomplete values:::');

            }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(compAction);
```

}

### ERROR:   Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0]

GETCOMPONENT:

```
          @AuraEnabled
public static string getComponent(string wrapval,string id) {
    String objectName;
    Criteria_Master__c cmas = new Criteria_Master__c();
    List < WrapperCriteria > warpList = (List < WrapperCriteria > )System.JSON.deserialize(wrapval, List<WrapperCriteria >.class);

    system.debug('::::::wrList value::::' + warpList);
    system.debug('id value ::::::' + id);

        WrapperCriteria ac=new WrapperCriteria ();
    List < SelectOption > ObjNames = new List < SelectOption > ();
    ObjNames.add(new SelectOption('', '--None--'));
    ObjNames.add(new selectoption('Pay_Element_Master__c', 'Pay Element'));
    ObjNames.add(new selectoption('CTC_Master__c', 'CTC Master'));

    Map <String,String> ctcMasAPINames = new Map < String, String > ();
    cmas = [select id, Name, Action_Criteria__c, Company_Master__c from Criteria_Master__c where Id=:id];

    if (warpList.size() > 0) {
        for (WrapperCriteria wr: warpList) {
            List <SelectOption > options = new List <SelectOption > ();
            if (wr.ObjectApiNAme == 'Pay_Element_Master__c') {
                for (SelectOption so: ObjNames) {
                    if (so.Value == wr.ObjectApiNAme) {
                        objectName = so.Label;
                        system.debug('****objectname *****' + objectName);
                    }
                }
                wr.SelObjectName = objectName;     //aassigned to wrapper


                for (Pay_Element_Master__c pem: [select id, name, Company_Master__c from Pay_Element_Master__c where Company_Master__c = : cmas.Company_Master__c]) {
                    options.add(new SelectOption(pem.id, pem.name));
                    //dc.componentMap.put(pem.id,pem.name);
                    ctcMasAPINames.put(pem.id, pem.name);
                    System.debug('--------Pay element MAster MAP VAlues-----' + ctcMasAPINames);
                }
                ac.Components = options;
                system.debug('ac.Components value:::::::'+ac.Components);
            } 
            else if (wr.ObjectApiNAme == 'CTC_Master__c') {
                for (SelectOption so: ObjNames) {
                    if (so.Value == wr.ObjectApiNAme) {
                        objectName = so.Label;
                        system.debug('-----------objectname --------------' + objectName);
                    }
                }
                wr.SelObjectName = objectName;
                Map < String, Schema.SObjectType > globalDescription = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
                Schema.sObjectType objType = globalDescription.get('CTC_Master__c');
                Schema.DescribeSObjectResult ob = objType.getDescribe();

                if (ob == Null) {
                    AuraHandledException e = new AuraHandledException('Invalid sObject Type');
                    e.setMessage('Invalid sObject Type');
                    system.debug(e);
                    throw e;

                }
                Map < String, Schema.SObjectField > mapFieldList = ob.fields.getMap();

                for (Schema.SObjectField field: mapFieldList.values()) {
                    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = field.getDescribe();
                    if (fieldResult.isAccessible() && (fieldResult.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Integer || fieldResult.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Double || fieldResult.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Currency)) {
                        options.add(new SelectOption(fieldResult.getName(), fieldResult.getLabel()));
                        //dc.componentMap1.put(fieldResult.getName(),fieldResult.getLabel());
                        ctcMasAPINames.put(fieldResult.getName(),fieldResult.getLabel());   
                    }
                }
                ac.Components1= options;
                system.debug('ac.Components1 value:::::::'+ac.Components1);
            }
        }
    }

    return JSON.serialize(ac);
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the `JSON string` value the method id returning?

Comment: please check the updated image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Basic `JSON string` with two properties `Components1` and `Components`:</strike>

<strike>var response = JSON.parse("{\"Components1\":[{\"value\":\"aId\"}], \"Components\":[{\"value\":\"CTC_Amount__c\"}]}");
    var data = JSON.parse(response);</strike>

**UPDATE**

Change return type to `WrapperCriteria` from `String`

```
public static WrapperCriteria getComponent(String wrapval, String id) {
```

Remove `JSON.parse`

```
alert(':::Data :::' + re.getReturnValue());
var data = re.getReturnValue();
/* Accessing values of Components1 */
if(data.Components1){
  for(var i = 0, len = data.Components1.length, i < len; i++){
    console.log(data.Components1[i].value); /* aId */
    /* console.log(data.Components1[i].anotherProperty); */
  }
}

/* Accessing values of Components */
if(data.Components){
  for(var i = 0, len = data.Components.length, i < len; i++){
    console.log(data.Components[i].value); /* CTC_Amount__c */
    /* console.log(data.Components[i].anotherProperty); */
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi itzmukshey,,,that components1 not only contains aId ,it contains other values also..like for example:ESI,FBP-CH etc... But in components contain only ctc amount and ctc pay...so that time how to modify your code...whether i have to pass all values to JSON.parse

Comment: Yes, you can add as many fields you want for `Components1` and `Components`;

Comment: I have tried your code..I got error...I have updated my code please check it

Comment: Why you are sending the `JSON` string from server send the `wrapper` as it is, then no need to parse it. Also, share the code of controller for `getComponent` method.

Comment: @AnnappaPH try the updated code;

Comment: `alert` won't show, you can use `console.log();` to check the values;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56342/discussion-between-annappa-ph-and-itzmukeshy7).